# Replace value of specific column in all non header rows

Tags: python, csv

Below is some python code that runs on a file similar to this (old_file.csv).

```
A,B,C,D
1,2,XX,3
11,22,XX,33
111,222,XX,333
```

How can I iterate through all lines in the old_file.csv (if I don't know the length of the file) and replace all values in column C or index 2 or cells[row][2] (based on cells[row][col]).  But I'd like to ignore the header row.  In the new_file.csv, all values containing 'XX' will become 'YY' for example.

```
import csv
r = csv.reader(open('old_file.csv'))
cells = [l for l in r]
cells[1][2] = 'YY'
cells[2][2] = 'YY'
cells[3][2] = 'YY'
w = csv.writer(open('new_file.csv', 'wb'))
w.writerows(cells)
```

Comment: Where is `lines` coming from?

Comment: should be "cells"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just small change in @Soviut ans, try this I think this will help you

```
import csv

rows = csv.reader(open('old_file.csv'))
newRows=[]
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    # ignore the first row, modify all the rest
    if i > 0:
        row[2] = 'YY'    
    newRows.append(row)
# write rows to new CSV file, no header is written unless explicitly told to
w = csv.writer(open('new_file.csv', 'wb'))
w.writerows(newRows)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can very easily loop over the array of rows and replace values in the target cell.

```
# get rows from old CSV file
rows = csv.reader(open('old_file.csv'))

# iterate over each row and replace target cell
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    # ignore the first row, modify all the rest
    if i > 0:
        row[2] = 'YY'

# write rows to new CSV file, no header is written unless explicitly told to
w = csv.writer(open('new_file.csv', 'wb'))
w.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Note that this would replace element in the header row too, which is not what you wanted. Actually a simple fix as in `for row in rows[1:]` will do the trick. But you got to handle the empty file, otherwise `IndexError` is possible.

Answer (score 0):

csv reader makes arrays, so you could just run it on `r[1:]`

Comment: Can you please be specific?  I've never written a Python script.

Comment: You asked how to ignore the header row. In your `for` loop, instead of running on `r`, run on `r[1:]`

Answer (score 0):

`len(cells)` is the number of rows. Iterating from 1 makes it skip the header line. Also the `lines` should be `cells`.

```
   import csv 
    r = csv.reader(open('old_file.csv'))
    cells = [l for l in r]
    for i in range(1, len(cells)):
        cells[i][2] = 'YY'
    w = csv.writer(open('new_file.csv', 'wb'))
    w.writerows(cells)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
read_handle = open('old_file.csv', 'r')
data = read_handle.read().split('\n')
read_handle.close()
new_data = []
new_data.append(data[0])
for line in data[1:]:
    if not line:
        new_data.append(line)
        continue
    line = line.split(',')
    line[2] = 'YY'
    new_data.append(','.join(line))
write_handle = open('new_file.csv', 'w')
write_handle.writelines('\n'.join(new_data))
write_handle.close()
```

Comment: First, this will fail with IndexError on empty file. Second, the `csv` is the built-in package of python, so when you are working with .csv files, it's much more preferably to use it.

Comment: I agree. Thanks. However, the answer is specific to the question and does not necessarily handle all possible error scenarios - like a line containing just 2 elements (so, line[2] will also raise an IndexError). As regards the csv module, if the usage is as simple as described in the que, I do not see any added benefits of using the csv module.

Comment: Here's a shell one liner (it trims off blank lines though):
head -1 old_file.csv && cat old_file.csv | awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NF && NR>1{$3="YY"; print}' | tee new_file.csv